# Which folder is used to create Newsfeed in PHPFOX V 3.7.2?

Tags: phpfox

I want to modify template  for *News Feed* so it looks better. 
I'm unable to find Which *folder/folders* is/are used to Create News feed IN `PHPFOX` since it contains almost 7000 files. 
Can any one help me in finding *folder/folders* for NewsFeed Template? This will very-2 appreciated. 
I'm using `PHPFOX v 3.7.2`. 
These folders `FILE`, `INCLUDE`, `INSTALL`, `MODULE`, `STATIC`, `THEME` are there. 
Which one is used and inside this folder which folder is used.

Answer (score 0):

The path is: \www\yourfoldername\module\feed\

Inside this folder are the files that are needed for the news feeds for editing.